# Recipient removed from address list when replying to all in GMail

Tags: gmail

When receiving a group email with multiple recipients in the "to" field in the GMail app on Android, I have noticed that when I "reply-all", one or more recipients are truncated from the address list. Has anyone else noticed this and is there a fix?

Comment: Never seen that. Are you sure you haven't accidentally tapped with your finger?

Comment: Yes, I tested several times. Funny thing is it does not happen with every single conversation, but it happens often. I tested it with several accounts and was able to reproduce it in each one.